# FInding a letter in VB script

Tags: c#, vba, vbscript

I'm making a scan line that uses the account number to figure out what the check digit should be. Some accounts have letters instead of numbers.  I need to replace letters with numbers.  I wrote something similar in C# but cannot figure out how to do it in VB Script.  Here is my c# code

```
    if(account2.Contains("T"))
       {
           int x = account2.IndexOf("T");
           temp = account2.Substring(2+x);
           account2 = ("3" + temp);
           Console.WriteLine(account2);
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
       if (account2.Contains("M"))
       {
           int x = account2.IndexOf("M");
           temp = account2.Substring(1+x);
           account2 = ("2" + temp);
           Console.WriteLine(account2);
           Console.ReadLine();
       }
```

Comment: Please do not tag VB.NET for questions regarding VB Script.  They are entirely different technologies.

Comment: Can you post a sample account number, before and after your C# code runs against it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My classic VB is kind of rusty, so this may not even compile, but it should point you in the right direction:

```vb
Dim x
x = InStr(account2, "T")
If x > 0 Then
    account2 = "3" & Mid(account2, x + 2)
    'probably not a good idea to read the next line here
End If
x = InStr(account2, "M")
If x > 0 Then
    account2 = "2" & Mid(account2, x + 1)
End If
```